# Captcha unreadable

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, captcha

There are just too many dots and lines in the default RWD captcha field. I've tried some of the suggestions here for reducing the noise and lines, but those were all 1.7CE edition solutions and I assume, 1.9.1 uses a different method, because nothing I've tried has worked.

I've tried changing and adding noise and line levels in the

/lib/Zend/Captcha/

But no results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit this file: /app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Zend.php

add this code after line 87

```
$this->setDotNoiseLevel(10);     // Added code
$this->setLineNoiseLevel(0);     // Added code
```

This overrides the lib/Zend/Captcha/Image.php file, which if you edit it, resets to default values ...

Apaarently, the 1.7CE answer works for 1.9.1CE, just slightly different file locations and names