# Reduce the difficulty of the Captcha

Tags: magento2, captcha

I applied captcha on customer registration page but many customers complained about the captcha is too difficult to read.

Is there any methods to reduce the difficulty of the Captcha?

There are a solution but the solution is for Magento 1.9 while I'm using Magento 2.3.x

[Captcha unreadable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49389/captcha-unreadable)

Comment: Try to use invisible Google Recaptcha it is much simpler

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322149/82670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to use Google's ReCaptcha v3 for this.

It has worked very well for us.

Assuming you are using 2.4.x here is the DevDocs

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html